# Создание сессии пользователя на FastApi

Tags: python, fastapi

Читал документацию [на официальном сайте](https://jordanisaacs.github.io/fastapi-sessions/guide/getting_started/). Создал все как там. Когда зашел на страницу **/whoami** из документации - пользователь не определился.

Начал шерстить инет. Нашел [пример](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/754), как писали там, рабочий. Прошел на страницу **/private** и увы тоже никакой сессии не получилось...

Кто создавал сессию пользователя на FastApi подскажите что и как надо? Либо манускрипт какой-нибудь укажите, по которому делали...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-общем, внимательно еще раз перечитал оф.документацию + еще кучу иностранных видео и реализовал это дело. Только маленько внес изменения:

```
pwd_context = CryptContext(schemes=['bcrypt'], deprecated='auto')


def get_password_hash(password):
    return pwd_context.hash(password)

class SessionData(BaseModel):
    username: str
    user_pass: str

    def get_inf(self):
        data = {
            'auth_': False,
            'username:': None,
            'user_pass': ''
        }
        if self.username:
            data = {
                'auth_': True,
                'username:': self.username,
                'user_pass': self.user_pass
            }
        return data

@app.post("/")
async def index(response: Response, email: str = Form(...), password: str = Form(...)):
    email=='try@email.ru' and password=='123':
        session = uuid4()
        data = SessionData(username=email,
                           user_pass=get_password_hash(password))

        await backend.create(session, data)
        cookie.attach_to_response(response, session)

        return RedirectResponse("/user_panel", status_code=303, headers=response.headers)
    return RedirectResponse("/", status_code=303)

@app.get("/user_panel", dependencies=[Depends(cookie)], response_class=HTMLResponse)
async def user_panel(request: Request, session_data: SessionData = Depends(verifier)):
    return templates.TemplateResponse("user_panel.html",
                                      {'request': request, **session_data.get_inf()})

@app.get("/logout", response_class=HTMLResponse)
async def logout(request: Request, response: Response, session_id: UUID = Depends(cookie)):
    await backend.delete(session_id)
    cookie.delete_from_response(response)
    return templates.TemplateResponse("logout_session.html",
                                      {"request": request, 'mes:': 'deleted session'})
```